# Storing selected radio button in wpf datagrid back to remote database

Tags: c#-4.0

Questions     Agree          Strongly Agree         Disagree         Strongly Disagree

Ques1            o                         o                  o                   o 
Ques2            o                         o                  o                   o 
Ques3            o                         o                  o                   o 
:
:
:

o represent Radio button
Each questions were given 4 radio buttons for selection

Hi All,

I have a datagrid in wpf application as the above template above.I retrieve all the questions from the remote database through web method.

I'm using the below xaml code for the radio buttons:

```
<Grid.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="AgreeTemplate" >
            <RadioButton GroupName="{Binding Path=question}" IsChecked="{Binding Agree, Mode=TwoWay}" Background="Purple" Height="30" />
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="StronglyAgreeTemplate" >
            <RadioButton GroupName="{Binding Path=question}" IsChecked="{Binding StroglyAgree, Mode=TwoWay}" Background="Purple" Height="30" />
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="DisagreeTemplate" >
            <RadioButton GroupName="{Binding Path=question}" IsChecked="{Binding Disagree, Mode=TwoWay}" Background="Purple" Height="30" />
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="StronglyDisagreeTemplate" >
            <RadioButton GroupName="{Binding Path=question}" IsChecked="{Binding StronglyDisagree, Mode=TwoWay}" Background="Purple" Height="30" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </Grid.Resources>


<DataGrid Name="dataGridFeedback" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Canvas.Left="9" Canvas.Top="6" Height="613" Width="1523" FontFamily="Comic Sans MS" FontSize="20" CanUserAddRows="false" CanUserDeleteRows="False" GridLinesVisibility="All" HeadersVisibility="All" AlternatingRowBackground="BlanchedAlmond" RowDetailsVisibilityMode="Visible" CanUserResizeColumns="False" CanUserResizeRows="False" CanUserSortColumns="False">
                <DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Questions" Width="800" IsReadOnly="True" Binding="{Binding Path=question}" />
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Agree" Width="180" IsReadOnly="True" CellTemplate="{StaticResource AgreeTemplate}" />
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Strongly Agree" Width="180" IsReadOnly="True" CellTemplate="{StaticResource StronglyAgreeTemplate}" />
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Disagree" Width="180" IsReadOnly="True" CellTemplate="{StaticResource DisagreeTemplate}" />
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Strongly Disagree" Width="180" IsReadOnly="True" CellTemplate="{StaticResource StronglyDisagreeTemplate}" />
                </DataGrid.Columns>
            </DataGrid>
```

However,all the radio buttons were having the same group name as [GroupName="{Binding Path=question}"],how could I know whether which answer has been selected by the user?

Another question is that is that correct to use  to define all those radio button? Is there any datagrid row property to be used in wpf datagrid?

Lastly how can I store the selected radio button for each question back to the remote database?

Please guide me.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Bad idea. If you have 4 radio buttons per question, only one radio button is to be checked, so the amount of information on the answer is the same as an integer value 0..3. Even if you had 256 buttons per question, you would need only 1 byte to store in the database. So, to store the answer to the question you need only one integer value — a number of the only checked radio button, only one button per question.

Also, your question is quite wrong ideologically. You need to store data, not state of the UI. You need to have a data layer and its binding to the UI, that's it. All data management should be done with the data layer, not UI. Once the data is updated, it should trigger a change in the UI presentation.

In connection to this, I suggest you learn and analyze applicability of the following architectural patterns(http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Architectural_pattern_(computer_science)[^]):

```
MVVM — Model View View Model,
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model_View_ViewModel[^],

MVC — Model-View-Controller,
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model-view-controller[^]),

MVA — Model-View-Adapter,
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model–view–adapter[^],

MVP — Model-View-Presenter,
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model-view-presenter[^].
```

Pay attention for the motivation of those architectures. If you understand it, you would be able to create better design ideas.